# How to debug the memory is changed randomly issue

Tags: c, debugging, memory, solaris

My application is a multi-thread program that runs on Solaris.

Recently, I found it may crash, and the reason is one member in a pointer array is changed from a valid value to `NULL`,so when accessing it, it crashed.

Because the occurrence ratio is very low, in the past 2 months, it only occurred twice, and the changed members in the array aren't the same. I can't find the repeated steps, and after reviewing code, there is no valuable clue gotten.

Could anyone give some advice on how to debug the memory is changed randomly issue?

Comment: Add a logging function at that site.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger, and set a memory watch on the memory location you're concerned about. This assumes it's a consistent memory location you can watch, though. Otherwise, something like valgrind might help find memory errors.

Comment: @Cornstalks:Because this issue occurred in production environment, I don't think it is possible to use debugger.

Comment: @C.R.:Because I don't know when and where the value is changed, where do I add trace?

Comment: @NanXiao: The logging function could dump the memory when it finds the pointer becomes null contrary to your expectation. Then you can examine the core dump with a debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you aren't able to reproduce the crash, debugging it isn't going to be easy.

However, there are some things you can do:

1. Go through the code and make a list of all of the places in the code that write to that variable--particularly the ones that could write a NULL to it.  It's likely that one of them is your culprit.
2. Try to develop some kind of torture test that makes the fault more likely to occur (eg running through simulated or random transactions at top speed).  If you can reproduce the crash this way you'll be in a much better situation, as you can then analyze the actual cause of the crash instead of just speculating.
3. If possible, run the program under valgrind or purify or similar.  If they give any warnings, track down what is causing those warnings and fix it; it's possible that your program is eg accessing memory that has been freed, which might seem to work most of the time (if the free memory hasn't been reused for anything when it is accessed) but would fail occasionally (when something is reusing it)
4. Add a memory checker like Electric Fence to your code, or just replace free() with a custom version that overwrites the free memory with random garbage in the hopes that this will make the crash more likely to occur.
5. Recompile your program using different compilers (especially new/fancy ones like clang++ with the static analyzer enabled) and fix whatever they warn about.  This may point you to your problem.
6. Run the program under different hardware and OS's; sometimes an obscure problem under one OS gives really obvious symptoms on another.
7. Review the various machines where the crash is known to have occurred.  Do they all have anything in common?  What about the machines where it hasn't crashed?  Is there something different about them?

Step 2 is really the most important one, because even if you think you have fixed the problem, you won't be able to prove it unless you can reproduce the crash in the old code, and cannot reproduce it with the fixed code.  Without being able to reproduce the fault, you're just guessing about whether a particular code change actually helps or not.

Comment: Good analysis — it really sounds like you've been through that process a few times!